# HTML to PDF and Forms authentication

Tags: html, forms, authentication, pdf, evopdf

I successfully used the EVO HTML to PDF tool in a previous project and now I'm trying to to integrate it in another project. The problem is that the page I have to convert is behind the ASP.NET forms authentication and when I convert the page I get the login form. How can I pass over forms authentication and get the page content in PDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to get the Forms Authentication cookie from current request and pass it to converter to be used when accessing the HTML page to convert:

```
HtmlToPdfConverter htmlToPdfConverter = new HtmlToPdfConverter();

// Add the Forms Authentication cookie to request
if (Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null)
{
    htmlToPdfConverter.HttpRequestCookies.Add(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
         Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value);
}

htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertUrl(urlToConvert);
```

Comment: I found this later on the website but after some research, and yes, this is the correct solution.